# two (or more) managed service factory with same pid?

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi

I have two managed service factories and both of them need the same set of configuration data.

- Is that ok to define multiple managed service factory with **same factory pid** in a single bundle?
- If the answer (for above question) is NO, then what is the proper way of defining above services without duplicating configuration data in two files?

ps: I'm using blueprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this from the specification:

> A service can register with multiple PIDs and PIDs can be shared
>   between multiple targets (both Managed Service and Managed Service
>   Factory targets) to receive the same information.

At least according to the spec, having multiple managed service factories with the same id is ok.